# Jekyll variable for all posts

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I would like to set up a variable to share across all posts to set up the expected location of images so I can do this:

```
![My sweet image]({{ post.images }}/sweet-image.png)
```

Which I eventually want to emit:

```
{{site.baseurl}}/images/posts/{{page.date | date: '%Y' }}
```

I've tried a bunch of things and cant seem to work out how to get anything to show up on the post object (for all pages).

Things I've tried (Ive ignored the variables component to try to make it simpler for now):

in post.html layout:

```
---
layout: default
b: 'bananas'
---
{% assign a = 'apples' %}
```

And then in a post:

```
{{a}}{{b}}
{{post.a}}{{post.b}}
```

None of these options seem to do anything. Im guessing im putting it in the wrong place or doing it wrong but im not too sure where I should be putting post-scoped variables.

Comment: Another way to do it is to create an include and every time I add a pic in a post {% include postimage.html a=a b=b %}

Comment: Ah yup that seems like a tidy alternative